# Запятая или тире ставится

Tags: запятые

Одно из них, озеро Смолина, является остатком древнего моря.
Можно ли ставить так запятую и на основании чего?

Comment: Тире, когда поясняется, что это такое. А здесь просто называется.

Comment: Тут две запятые на одном основании.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере можно усмотреть как отношения пояснения, так и уточнения.

Одно из них(а именно), озеро Смолина, является остатком древнего моря.Здесь раскрывается значение местоимения.

Одно из них, озеро Смолина, является остатком древнего моря. Говорится о множестве озер, а потом о конкретном, т. е. об озере Смолина.